# Changing a button text in tkinter - 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to have Button1 change the text on it from 'hi' to 'bye' when it is pressed, and back again when pressed a second time.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def toggletext():
  if Button1["text"] == "hi":
    Button1["text"] = "bye"
    Game.update()
  else:
    Button1["text"] = "hi"
    Game.update()

Game = Tk()
Game.wm_title("title")
Button1 = Button(text="hi",fg="white",bg="purple",width=2,height=1,command=toggletext).grid(row=0,column=0)
Button2 = Button(fg="white",bg="purple",width=2,height=1).grid(row=1,column=0)
Button3 = Button(fg="white",bg="purple",width=2,height=1).grid(row=0,column=1)
Button4 = Button(fg="white",bg="purple",width=2,height=1).grid(row=1,column=1)

Game.mainloop()
```

I get this error when I press Button1:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\gridtest2.py", line 4, in toggletext
    if Button1["text"] == "hi":
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: BTW: you don't need `Game.update()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NoneType` is the type of the `None` value. `Button1` is set to `None`.

That's because the `.grid()` method returns `None` and that's what you store:

```
Button1 = Button(...).grid(row=0,column=0)
```

Create the button *first*, then call `.grid()` separately:

```
Button1 = Button(
    text="hi", fg="white", bg="purple", width=2, height=1, 
    command=toggletext)
Button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much.